# Windows Java -Xmx and -Xms unable set by command prompt

Tags: java, windows

i try to increase the java -Xmx and -Xms , i have try use the command to as

```
javaw -XX:+MaxPermSize=8192M
```

*it show Error message of Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. A fatal exception has occured.Program will exit*

And also try to add new Environment Variable for java as

```
Variable name =_JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value = Xmx8192M
```

After set finish i try to use the command to check for the MaxheapSize it show "0".

Comment: Do you run a 64 bit JVM?

Comment: Do you really need an 8 GB PermGen?  That's an awful lot of code. IntelliJ has a lot of code and it only uses 350 MB.

Comment: @Ferrybig i run in 64bits windows server , and the installation of java is 1.7 64bits

Comment: On the versions on 7 I have, from 7u25 up but NOT 7u05, those two lines are preceded by `Unexpected +/- setting in VM option ...` which explains the problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 the version i have is jdk-7u71-windows-x64

Comment: I don't have 7u71 (when they issue patch and minor releases together like 7u71,72 I usually only take the latter) but 7u67 and 7u72 both give me the specific error.

Answer (score 0):

While running your application you can set it like this :

```
java -XX:PermSize=8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=8192m -jar application.jar
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i don't require a .jar for testing